# Redmine "generate_autologin_token" got NULL value for "id" variable. Where "id" is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have an issue similar to https://www.redmine.org/boards/4/topics/59980 with authentication using open_id plugin on my redmine instance.

I got a traceback to [redmine\app\models\user.rb](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/user.rb) (app/models/user.rb:445: in
`generate_autologin_token')

```
  # Generates a new autologin token and returns its value
  def generate_autologin_token
    token = Token.create!(:user_id => id, :action => 'autologin')
    token.value
  end
```

So, the issue is that "id" is NULL in some rare cases when it should be user id number. I'm inexperienced in RoR and failed to find where this "id" variable is defined in user.rb to debug further.

Where can I find this variable definition in a redmine project? Also if someone already solved or knows hot to solve a similar issue I will really appreciate a debugging advice or a solution

Comment: It seems that authentication has been failed and no user has been found. No user hence no id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you've defined "id" variable, but if your method "generate_autologin_token" is inside "User" Model, you can use self.id to use the user id at the instance.
EDIT: If you call "id" before_save or not a particular instance of a User, it'll be NULL obviously.

Comment: I've not defined "id", it's in a user.rb which is a part of Redmine project https://www.redmine.org/. That's why i have a difficulty - it's just "id", not self.id, not user.id, i can't  find where is the  origin of that 'id' thing

Comment: In rails "id" is the default primary key which you can use in your model, For example, at the instance "id" points to the instance of the User Model, (a Row's id column)